# How to describe the SE voting system in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin

I would like to express the following ideas in Latin, for the purpose of describing this site:

1. Through voting, the best answers rise to more visible positions at the top of the page.
2. You can vote on questions and answers, making the best questions and answers more visible.

My current translations are:

1. *Suffragando responsus optimi moventur sursum et pessimi deorsum.*
2. *Potes scripta aliorum suffragari et ita substantiam optimam promovere.*

Is *suffragari* a good verb for the kind of voting we have on this site?
Whatever the most suitable verb is, how does it work syntactically?
I was unable to figure out whether *suffragari* is transitive or not.
How could I improve my translations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go for *suffragiis* or *per suffragia* in the first translation instead of *suffragando* and *suffragium ferre* instead of *suffragari*.

I'd go with *quis* instead of *potes*, though it's a rare enough word that confusion with the nominative interrogative pronoun would probably arise. So maybe *licet* as in "it is possible")?

And rather than *substantiam promovere* I'd go with *roganda responsaque optima conspicuiora ferre* or maybe *inlustrare*, but then again as soon as anything gets abstract in Latin I start having trouble understanding it, so *substantiam promovere* might be better.

Comment: Thanks! *Suffragiis* or *per suffragia* and *suffragium ferre* sound good. *Quire* is indeed a little problematic, but perhaps *licere* would indeed be a good substitute for *posse* in some cases. Regarding the last paragraph, I wanted to keep things simple. The words "question" and "answer" with their corresponding verbs are used so often in the surrounding text that a more general word for content is good (also in English, I suppose).

Comment: Maybe then I'd go with *verba*? But as I say I'm biased against things like *substantia(m)*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yeah, looking at the L&S definition for *substantia* ("that of which a thing consists, the being, essence, contents, material, substance; fortune, substance, property; worldly goods") I think it's probably not the way to go. Maybe *Scripta aliorum quæ suffragia accipiunt promota sunt.*

Comment: Hmm... I looked at the very same definition and decided that it is the way to go. I was looking for a word for "content", and that seemed to match it better than others. The point of voting is to promote the best content. But *scripta* is a good option, too.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yeah, I think here "content" is another idea for which we use an abstraction when Latin would use a concrete word.